# Adding a value to Firebase node instead of overwriting what's already there

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to add a value into a Firebase node, and my current code is overwriting what's already there.

I have my database setup like this (I'm trying to add a UID to "participants"):

```
"rooms" : {
    "-Ki6fAHv6LS5pyx34nUr" : {
      "messages" : {
        "-Ki70oJOAsto1uIxJsLY" : {
          "senderId" : "tzfHgGKWLEPzPU9GvkO4XE1QKy53",
          "senderName" : "Timothy",
          "text" : "Test"
        }
      },
      "participants" : {
        "tzfHgGKWLEPzPU9GvkO4XE1QKy53" : true
      },
      "roomName" : "Room One"
    }
```

This is the code I have, run when a user searches for another user, then taps the result:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    // Add selected user's UID to current room's participants
    let currentRoomParticipantsRef: FIRDatabaseReference = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("rooms").child(currentRoomID).child("participants")

    let newParticipantItem = [self.returnedUsersUID : true]
    currentRoomParticipantsRef.setValue(newParticipantItem)

    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Added!", message: "Your friend has been added to the room", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.actionSheet)

    let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.cancel, handler: {(alert :UIAlertAction!) in
    })
    alertController.addAction(okAction)

    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Doing this overwrites the UID[s] already listed in "participants" with the new value. How can I add the new UID to the list, instead of overwriting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `setValue` (which does indeed replace the entire node with your new dictionary), try using [`updateChildValues`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Classes/FIRDatabaseReference#/c:objc(cs)FIRDatabaseReference(im)updateChildValues:), which will update values (or create new ones) without overwriting keys that already exist.

Comment: Perfect! That's what I needed. I can accept the answer in 6 minutes. Thanks again!